# AngularJS Sorting of array nested in JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs

GOAL : Setup a table that is sortable after data is returned from our server.

Data Format Returned from server :

```
{
    "result" : {
        "code" : "OK",
        "msg" : ""
    },
    "data" : [{
            "row" : ["Fred", "64233", "197"]
        }, {
            "row" : ["Steve", "158879", "36"]
        }, {
            "row" : ["Ted", "115222", "12"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Limitation : Can't change the data format the server returns.  The data that I want sortable is contained in the array in the "row" object.  I tried doing things like

```
<tr ng-repeat="roll in myWelcome.data" | orderBy:'roll.row[1]'">
   <td>{{ roll.row[0] }}</td><td>{{ roll.row[1] }}</td><td>{{ roll.row[2] }}</td>
</tr>
```

but it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: "but it didn't work" What does that mean?

Comment: not sure that orderBy will work without being able to pass it an object property name. Does code work without orderBy? Probably have to create custom filter for ordering

Comment: The data displays correctly in the table, but is not sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest transforming your data into something a little more standard. It will enable you to better maintain and reason about the code.

Since you can't change the format of the data the server sends you, you can just change it once it arrives on the client.

```
fetchData(results) {
   // Transform the results we get back from the server.
   this.myWelcomeData = results.data.map(function(input) {
      return {
         name: input.row[0],
         id: input.row[1],
         age: input.row[2]
      }
   });
}
```

Then you can order using the normal Angular repeater syntax:

```
<tr ng-repeat="roll in myWelcomeData" | orderBy:'id'">
```

Comment: This worked.  I put it right after my $http.get statement
I changed the first two lines to :
  .then(function(response) {
  $scope.myWelcome = response.data.data.map(function(input) {

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend organizing your data when it's returned from the server to make it more usable. Failing that, you could simply implement a custom filter that knows where to look.

```
<tr ng-repeat="roll in myWelcome.data | customOrderBy:1">
```

Filter:

```
angular.module("Your_App").filter("customOrderBy", [function() {
    return function(data, index) {
         return data.sort(function(o) {
             return o.row[index];
         });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the newb question, but where do I put this function?  I tried right after my  $scope.getRequest = function () { and it says, (intermediate value)(intermediate value).filter is not a function

Comment: You need to register it with your angular app. I updated the answer.